# cannot find symbol. class ownership and visibility

Tags: java

i've been writing an RPG-ish game as a (re)learning tool for java
but seeing as posting code on this site is kinda difficult, i made a simplified version to post

The compile errors arise on the God class, when calling persons getters(cannot find symbol)

```
    class God{      
        psvm(s [] args){
            s.o.p("I create people and stuff and try to tell you about it")
            People godsCreatedPerson = new People();
            Stuff godsCreatedStuffForTheCreatedPerson = new Stuff();

            s.o.p("Im the persons creator, so I should know stuff about him and his stuff");
            s.o.p("Im going to try to tell you about my created person now:" + godsCreatedPerson.getPeopleNumberOfLegs);        //error cannot find symbol
            s.o.p("Im going to try again:" + godsCreatedPerson.getPeopleNumberOfFingers);           //error cannot find symbol
            s.o.p("but I cant tell you, even though I created this person, and I have his getters")
}
```

}

Another compile error(cannot find symbol too) arise on the People class when calling Stuff object, created by the God class

```
    class People{
        s.o.p("I have setters");


        s.o.p("I have getters for my creator, so I can tell him about myself");
        public int getPeopleNumberOfLegs(){
            return myNumberOfLegs;
        }
        public int getPeopleNumberOfFingers(){
            return myNumberOfFingers;
        }


        void imGoingToTryToDoSomethingWithTheStuffIOwnButDidntCreate(){
            personsAttempt = godsCreatedStuffForTheCreatedPerson.doSomethingWithMe()    //Person = God.Stuff
            s.o.p("hmm it seems I cant do it, because I didnt CREATE the stuff");       //error cannot find symbol

        }
    }
```

no error on the Stuff class, since it doesnt call the God nor the Person class

```
    class Stuff{
        s.o.p("i have getters and setters");
        s.o.p("i have methods too!!");
        void doSomethingWithMe(){
        }

        s.o.p("no problems with me, because I dont call my creator nor my owner");
    }
```

Comment: s.o.p("Is this new syntax in Java?");

Comment: I love the class names. And s.o.p is the new syntax in Java, really?

Comment: You are calling methods on those two lines `s.o.p("Im going to try to tell you about my created person now:" + godsCreatedPerson.getPeopleNumberOfLegs);
s.o.p("Im going to try again:" + godsCreatedPerson.getPeopleNumberOfFingers);`. You should some research before posting, you are using wrong syntax (syntax you can read in the very first of every Java tutorial):

Comment: "s.o.p" is just shorthand for "System.out.println". I expect the poster was just trying to simplify the example.

Comment: 1. Are you using any packages ?? Are your classes in different packages?? 2. If they are all in different packages then check whether they all are declared as public or not. This may solve your problem.

Comment: Aayush, I am not using packages. They're all in the same directory. I've set the classes as public, still no go. Mardavi thank you, that was a big oversight on my part. It fixed some errors, but not all that are related to it, which is quite puzzling since the remaining errors are similar in structure to the corrected lines. Im still tracing

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler cannot find the other classes. Make sure they are all being compiled and are in the classpath.

Without knowing how you are building your project it would be difficult to advise on this, but assuming you are using javac directly, this might be:

```
javac -classpath . Stuff.java People.java God.java
```